# Telegram Bot - Same username , Different nicknames for his/her friends

Tags: php, telegram-bot

In Telegram ,for example we have a user with first name= Jim and last name=Smith.
He may have a public username or not.(no problem) and has a unique id.
Already you know this person is known for his friend with different names(niknames) in telegram contact list and in chats or groups, someone may see "Jimmm", the other see him "My best friend" the other see him "J S" and so on.

The question is how to send a message to a group and **mention him**  (**Via BOT**) that he and his friends are in that group ,and mention him so that each friend see this message in his/her own way.(No 1. friend see him "Jimmm", the next see him "My best friend" and the third see him "J S").
**The Problem is mentioning of him** in a message ,in a way that everyone see him in themselves manner.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Send messages with user ids, and "decode" the message at the reciever by comparing user id with users contact list?

Comment: Sending with Id is Ok. but HOW should i decode? and for how many peapole? each one should see in his own manner and i think Telegram should do that. please explain more

Comment: You send them with user ids like for example: `{user 11}` and in the readmessage.php you create two arrays with userids and nicknames from the readers contact list. Then you do a `str_replace("{user". arrayid ."}", arraynicknames, message)` this way `{user 11}` will be matched in arrayid and be replaced with arraynicknames in message.

Comment: I want to send a message like this to group:  `Hello  "Jim Smith"`  and group member No.1 should see this message `Hello "Jimmm"` , No.2 should see 'Hello "My best friend"` and No3. `Hello "J S"` all in that group.One group with one message but every one see it differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. but i couldn't know how to implement it. how to get `arraynicknames` that you mentioned. I am reading the `https://core.telegram.org/bots/api` but i couldn't find anything related to your advice.